# Regex to match word ending OR beginning with a hyphen

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to create a regex that would remove any word that either starts or ends with a hyphen (not both).

`word1-` -> remove
`-word2` -> remove
`sub-word` ->keep

My attempt is the following:

```
def begin_end_hyphen_removal(line):
    return re.sub(r"((\s+|^)(-[A-Za-z]+)(\s+|$))|((\s+|^)([A-Za-z]+-)(\s+|$))","",line)
```

However, when I try to apply it on the following lines:

```
here are some word sub-words -word1 word2- sub-word2 word3- -word4
-word5 example
word6-
word7-
another one -word8
-word9
```

I get the same input as output again.

Comment: The only unclear part is what to do with `-some-`. I understood it should not be matched ("*remove any word that either starts or ends with a hyphen **(not both)***").

Comment: what about `-sub1-sub2`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes I want to keep it if it is `-some-`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
r'\b(?<!-)[A-Za-z0-9]+-\B|\B-[A-Za-z0-9]+\b(?!-)'
r'\b(?<!-)\w+-\B|\B-\w+\b(?!-)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N78rts/1). *Details*:

- `\b(?<!-)\w+-\B` - one or more word chars that are not preceded with `-` and then a `-` char that is either at the end of string or before a non-word char
- `|` - or
- `\B-\w+\b(?!-)` - a `-` that is either at the start of string or after a non-word char and then one or more word chars that are not followed with `-`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FqoG9M):

```py
import re
rx = re.compile( r' *(?:\b(?<!-)\w+-\B|\B-\w+\b(?!-))' )
text = 'here are -some- word sub-words -word1 word2- sub-word2 word3- -word4\n-word5 example\nword6-\nword7-\nanother one -word8\n-word9'
print( rx.sub('', text) )
```

Output:

```
here are -some- word sub-words sub-word2
 example


another one
```

Comment: And what if I want to include special characters not only [A-Za-z0-9]? For example remove something like `ms$g- `

Comment: @M.A.G Try `re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(-\S+-)(?!\S)|(?<!\S)-\S+(?![\S-])|(?<![\S-])\S+-(?!\S)', r'\1', text)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N78rts/2).

Comment: It works perfectly, but do you have any idea why doesn't my solution work in general? I am curious to know

Comment: @M.A.G First, your main pattern matches only letters, but your strings can contain digits, too, and it appears, any non-whitespace chars. Besides, you consume whitespaces on both ends (`\s+` in groups with `^` and `$`), so you can't match consecutive matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pattern = r"(?=\S*['-])([a-zA-Z'-]+)"
test_string = '''here are some word sub-words -word1 word2- sub-word2 word3- -word4
-word5 example
word6-
word7-
another one -word8
-word9'''
result = re.findall(pattern, test_string)
print(result)
```

Comment: Adding some commentary would make the answer more valuable

Answer (score 1):

You could repeat matching word characters preceded or followed by a `-`

If you have words that are separated by a hyphen, and that end on a hyphen that you also want to remove like for example `sugar-free-`:

```
(?<!\S)(?:-\w+(?:-\w+)*|\w+(?:-\w+)*-)(?!\S)
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` Whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-\w+(?:-\w+)*` Match `-` and word chars, optionally repeated by `-` and word chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\w+(?:-\w+)*-` Match word chars optionally repeated by `-` and word chars
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?!\S)` Whitespace boundary to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nwIoM9/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/F0toaJ).

**Note** that in the pattern that you tried, you use `\s`, but note that it could also match a newline.

If you don't want to remove the newlines, you can use `[^\S\n]*` instead of `\s*`.

Example

```
import re

def begin_end_hyphen_removal(line):
    return re.sub(r"\s*(?<!\S)(?:-\w+(?:-\w+)*|\w+(?:-\w+)*-)(?!\S)", "", line)


s = ("here are some word sub-words -word1 word2- sub-word2 word3- -word4\n"
     "-word5 example\n"
     "word6-\n"
     "word7-\n"
     "another one -word8\n"
     "-word9")
print(begin_end_hyphen_removal(s))
```

Output

```
here are some word sub-words sub-word2 example
another one
```